# Explain the syntax for calling mutate on the Apollo client

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

```
client.mutate[1]({
    mutation[2]: gql`
        mutation[3] signOut[4] {
            signOut[5] {
                success[6]
            }
        }
    `,
});
```

The numbers in brackets are my annotations to the different parts of the query. My best guesses on their meaning are below. Correct me where I am wrong or incomplete. My biggest doubts are in italic:

**[1] client.mutate** There is a mutate method on the Apollo client because the Apollo client handles mutations differently than queries

**[2] mutation** Just an object property named mutation that is passed to the Apollo client

**[3] mutation** The root mutation field on the server

**[4] signOut** A field available on the mutation root field. *I am surprised that signOut is written immediately after mutation instead of on its own row within a pair of brackets*

**[5] signOut** I guess the signOut field on the server resolves to return  another field called signOut? *Am I understanding this correctly? Is this normal?*

**[6] success** The inner singOut field resolves to return an object  called success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding **[4] signOut** and **[5] signOut** that is the name you give to the mutation.

For example:

```
mutation signOut {
  signOut {
    success
  }
}
```

Is the same mutation as

```
mutation logOut {
  signOut {
    success
  }
}
```

The `method` triggered on both mutation is `signOut` but they have different names(`logOut` & `signOut`).

All the other points are correct.

**Notes:**

The `name` of the mutation(or query) is only for the client, the server has no definition of naming mutations.

The point to have 2 levels in one mutation is because you can trigger multiple mutations in one mutation, for example: given the requisite `the user signs out and unsubscribes to notifications` we could build one mutation like:

```
mutation logOutAndUnsubscribe {
  signOut {
    success
  }
  unsubscribe {
    success
  }
}
```

In this case we are naming the mutation `logOutAndUnsubscribe` that triggers 2 mutations `signOut` and `unsubscribe`. And again, the server implements `signOut` and `unsubscribe`, but has zero knowledge about `logOutAndUnsubscribe`.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please expand on: A) Does the name on the client need to match the name on the server, or will the correct data be returned anyway? B) What is the point of having two levels of names, signOut > signOut alternatively logOut > logOut instead of simply signOut?